# How can I divide this clause?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, relative-clauses, clauses, linguistics

How can I divide this clause from spoken text, in order to analyse the theme and type of the clauses?

Announcer: Welcome back everyone, so doctors are warning people to not take pain relievers like Tylenol and Advil before getting a covid-19 vaccine and joining us now to discuss this is Dr Shan Soe-Lin from the Jackson Institute of Global Affairs at Yale University, Dr Soe Lin thank you so much for being with us.

Comment: The last edit has **entirely** changed the question, which makes the already posted answer look like it's not really an answer. If you want to ask a new question, you should post it as such.

Comment: It's very poorly punctuated.  It's at least 4 separate sentences.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I feel, like, it's kind of what your show is as well.

Yes, I think – as it were – [that] it is also the same kind of thing as your show is.

Yes, I think – as it were – [that] it also resembles the nature of your show.

**Yeah**, Interjection of agreement

**I feel**, - it is my opinion

**like**, - concessive interjection

**[that] it's kind of** – [that] it resembles

**what your show is** – the nature of your show

**as well.** - also

Comment: Nicely done! My first thought was to sweep half the text away as meaningless "fillers", but you've deftly avoided that.

Comment: thank you very much